# Issue related to sencha touch toolbars

Tags: sencha-touch

I am very new to sencha touch. I am developing an App using sencha. I had added three buttons to toolbar. Among those three buttons when I click on one button the toolbar should have added with two more buttons dynamically in button click.My code is as follows:

```
this.profitChartToolbar = new Ext.Toolbar({         
        ui:'max',
        items: [this.qButton,this.hButton,this.yButton]
    });
```

In this way i added three buttons to toolbar. now when click on any one of the buttons i want to add two more buttons along with those three buttons. Can anyone share the solution for this ASAP.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide the previous buttons by using `button.hide()`
and u can add your custom buttons by function `button.add` to the existing toolbar

Answer (score 0):

funny task :)

```
var fnCreateTwoButtons = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        this.profitChartToolbar.add({
            text: 'New Button #' + i);
        });
    }
};
this.qButton.on('tap', fnCreateTwoButtons, this);
this.hButton.on('tap', fnCreateTwoButtons, this);
this.yButton.on('tap', fnCreateTwoButtons, this);
```

not tested...